# Where to see logs of device connecting/disconnecting events in Windows?

Tags: windows, usb, event-viewer, plug-and-play

When I connect devices to my Windows machine, the "upwards" sound is heard. When I disconnect it -- the "downwards" sound is heard.

Is there a way to find events, corresponding to these sounds in event viewer?

I want to see what device was connected and how successful it was.

**UPDATE**

This is USB device.